# need to one more thing mini length =8

Tags: linux, passwords

this is my pam file 
here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)

```
password        required        pam_cracklib.so difok=1 minlen=8 dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=0 
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so use_authtok sha512
```

here's the fallback if no module succeeds

```
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
```

prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already; 
this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code since the modules above will each just jump around

```
password        required                        pam_permit.so
```

and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)

```
password       optional   pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

end of pam-auth-update config

Comment: And the question is? Is there a secret message hidden in your question?

Comment: sorry i need to set mini length password to 8 and the above paragraph is my pam file without hashes we cannot post hashes in the sites

Comment: help Me to solve this

Comment: It is still not clear what you are asking. You should explain what exactly is not working, and how it should work, and what you expect. You already have the code `minlen=8` in your example, did it not work, did you get error messages, ...? I can recommend to read this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help) about how to ask good questions first.